# How can I test a command line Java app from JUnit, without mocking?

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

This is my code:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    // reconfigure global logging
    // do something else
  }
}
```

How can I test this from JUnit (or maybe not) *without mocking*? I want this `main()` function to do exactly what it would do normally and then catch its console output for assertions. Of course, without disturbing other tests with the reconfiguration of global logging, as mentioned above. Basically, I need a new JVM to run it.

Comment: Do exactly that.

Comment: what do you mean: 'catch its console output'?

Comment: @Stultuske well, it will print something to the console, I want to get it and pass to JUnit assertions for validation

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set (to mock, actually) `System.out` before your test, for example:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.print("Console output");
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
@Test
public void canPrint() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(os));

    Foo.main();

    assertEquals("Console output", os.toString());
}
```